# getNodeAt recursively java

Tags: java, recursion

I need to write `getNodeAt()` method recursively.

This is the original method:

```
private Node getNodeAt(int givenPosition) {
    Node currentNode=firstNode;
    for (int i =0; i < givenPosition; i++)
        currentNode=currentNode.next;
    return currentNode;
}
```

This is my attempt:

```
private Node getNodeAt(int givenPosition) {
    Node currentNode;
    if (givenPosition == 0) {
        return currentNode = firstNode;
    } else {
        return getNodeAt(givenPosition - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must advance some `Node` reference to the next node in each recursive call, which means you need an additional argument :

```
private Node getNodeAt(Node currentNode, int givenPosition) {
    if (givenPosition == 0){
        return currentNode;
    }else {
        return getNodeAt(currentNode.next, givenPosition - 1);
    }
}
```

And the initial call to the method would be

```
Node node = getNodeAt (firstNode, someIndex);
```

or you can create an additional method that will contain the initial call :

```
public Node getNodeAt(int givenPosition) {
    return getNodeAt (firstNode, givenPosition);
}
```